# Force JSON serialization of numbers to specific precision

Tags: ruby, json

Consider the following code that is intended to round numbers to the nearest one-hundredth and serialize the result to JSON:

```
require 'json'
def round_to_nearest( value, precision )
  (value/precision).round * precision
end
a = [1.391332, 0.689993, 4.84678]
puts a.map{ |n| round_to_nearest(n,0.01) }.to_json
#=> [1.3900000000000001,0.6900000000000001,4.8500000000000005]
```

Is there a way to use JSON to **serialize all numbers with a specific level of precision**?

```
a.map{ ... }.to_json( numeric_decimals:2 )
#=> [1.39,0.69,4.85]
```

This could be either with the Ruby built-in JSON library or another JSON gem.

**Edit**: As noted in comments to answers below, I'm looking for a general solution to all JSON serialization for arbitrary data that includes numbers, not specifically a flat array of numbers.

---

*<sup>Note that the above problem can be fixed in this specific case by rewriting the method:</sup>*

```
def round_to_nearest( value, precision )
  factor = 1/precision
  (value*factor).round.to_f / factor
end
```

*<sup>...but this does not solve the general desire to force a precision level during serialization.</sup>*

Comment: thanks for your feedback, I unfortunately share your conclusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just pre-round it using ruby's built-in round method: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Float.html#method-i-round

```
a.map{ |n| n.round(2) }.to_json
```

That looks clean to me instead of getting all types of custom libraries and passing in arguments.

Edit for comment:

I know you can do that with activesupport.

```
# If not using rails
require 'active_support/json'

class Float
  def as_json(options={})
    self.round(2)
  end
end

{ 'key' => [ [ 3.2342 ], ['hello', 34.1232983] ] }.to_json
# => {"key":[[3.23],["hello",34.12]]}
```

More exact solution: [better monkey-patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743835/force-json-serialization-of-numbers-to-specific-precision/11746479#11750364)

Comment: The former is a nice suggestion, but irrelevant to the JSON serialization. You're fixing the problem in Ruby for one particular data structure, not in general. The latter has a similar issue. What if I wanted to serialize `{nums:[1.111,2.222,3.333]}` or `{v1:1.111,v2:2.222,v3:3.333}`?

Comment: Thanks, the ActiveSupport JSON lib + `as_json` works a charm. I've added my own answer with a more elegant solution, but I'll give you the accept for pointing out what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Since the built-in JSON library does not call `#as_json` or `#to_json` on Numerics (presumably for speed) we can use the [ActiveSupport](http://as.rubyonrails.org/) library from Rails (without needing Rails).

We do our monkey-patch delicately, so that it only takes effect when a user-specified option is passed when calling `to_json`:

```ruby
require 'active_support/json' # gem install activesupport

class Float
  def as_json(options={})
    if options[:decimals]
      value = round(options[:decimals])
      (i=value.to_i) == value ? i : value
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

data = { key: [ [ 2.991134, 2.998531 ], ['s', 34.127876] ] }
puts data.to_json             #=> {"key":[[2.991134,2.998531],["s",34.127876]]}
puts data.to_json(decimals:2) #=> {"key":[[2.99,3],["s",34.13]]}
```

As shown in the last example, there's a little extra code used to convert integer-valued-floats to pure integers, just so that serialization doesn't waste bytes outputting `3.00` and can instead put just `3` (the same value in JSON and JS).

Answer (score 0):

Because you are dealing with floating-point, I'm inclined to say to convert to strings using format strings, and pass those. They'd allow you to set the precision nicely:

```
a = [1.391332, 0.689993, 4.84678]
a.map{ |f| '%.2f' % f }
=> ["1.39", "0.69", "4.85"]
```

If you want true floats, convert them back:

```
a.map{ |f| ('%.2f' % f).to_f }
=> [1.39, 0.69, 4.85]
```

From that point you could write something to override JSON's default Array serializer, or the Float serializer, however JSON does it, with one that accepts the precision, or format-string, you want.

---

Just to clarify, the use of `to_f` would occur before serializing, which would not bloat the resulting JSON output or force any sort of "magic" on the receiving side. Floats would transfer and be deserialized as floats:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'json'
true
irb(main):002:0> a = [1.391332, 0.689993, 4.84678]
[
    [0] 1.391332,
    [1] 0.689993,
    [2] 4.84678
]
irb(main):003:0> a.map{ |f| ('%.2f' % f).to_f }.to_json
"[1.39,0.69,4.85]"
irb(main):004:0> JSON.parse(a.map{ |f| ('%.2f' % f).to_f }.to_json)
[
    [0] 1.39,
    [1] 0.69,
    [2] 4.85
]
```

Start with something like:

```
class Float
  def to_json
    ('%.2f'%self).to_f
  end
end
(355.0/113).to_json # => 3.14
```

and figure out how to apply it to an array of Floats. You'll probably need to use the pure Ruby JSON though.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion, but this works around the problem and doesn't solve it generally. Imagine megabytes of JSON with mixed arrays and objects containing numeric values, and the desire to shrink the raw JSON size. Including two quotes where none are needed is a bit harsh; deserializing and distinguishing real strings from numbers-as-strings is not a great idea.

Comment: -1 This is an wrong approach. This will deserialize to string by the json parser and will force custom parser to get them back to numbers.

Comment: @JonasFagundes and @Phrogz, the second conversion, using `to_f` doesn't do what you are saying, as the values would be passed as floats in the desired precision.

Comment: @theTinMan Sorry, I thought you were suggesting using `to_f` during deserialization, not just as a simple form of rounding.

Answer (score -2):

1. Precision should not be handled during serialization;
2. Probably you have some semantic on these numbers that you are not making it explicit (maybe is Currency value? and maybe this is a quick and dirty script that doesn't need to make this semantic explicit) and
3. Using float pointing numbers as your implementation when what your program really needs precision is a bad approach for the problem. Floating point numbers has inherent inaccuracy in their representation ([Floating Point Accuracy Problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point_numbers#Accuracy_problems) ). Use BigDecimal instead.

Comment: No, there is no semantic on these values. These are not dollars and cents. In my current problem they happen to be monotonic tf*idf search result weightings, but you see a similar problem in something like numeric coordinates for 2D and 3D scenes. (Illustrator, for example, has an arbitrary precision selector when exporting SVG to control the trade off between small file size vs. precise coordinates.)

Comment: Phrogz, still, arbitrary precision numbers works better in this case than floating point numbers.

Comment: "Work better"? Yes, they provide more precision. However, a) the precision is not always needed (on a 10,000 unit square diagram, I truly don't need to know that a corner point is at 1.3132123413251366), and b) they work worse (the opposite of better) when file sizes matter.

Comment: Phrogz, 1. Yes, arbitrary precision can double up the size of your data structure; 2. It depends of you serialize them :). If you can leave with rounding errors keep using floats. If file size matter, choose a better serialization format for your data, json is too verbose for that, just as an example, protocol buffer can be used as a serialization format and it is many times smaller.

Comment: I would have upvoted the answer if it was valid. But `BigDecimal#to_s` returns `...eX` instead of just the original representation. So not what the question was about.